# Ways to measure React Native app startup performance

Tags: android, ios, performance, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to use something like Systrace to understand what's taking time on RN app startup. I've tried to trigger Systrace programmatically from the native code, but no success so far.

I want to get timings for such things as loading and parsing jsbundle, native operations like reading from fs, building react tree and initial render.

What are the tools I could use?

I'm working on an iOS app, but I'm also curious if there's any difference to what you'd use for Android.